# ask for app rating or review in Google Play, when uninstalling app

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-services

I vaguely fondly remember a time when Google Play (Google Store back then?) was pesturing me to leave a review every time I was uninstalling an app.

How can I enable this feature in Android 6?

Comment: This feature is independent of Android version- it is a matter of Play Store policies which keep getting added or sunset

Comment: Wait, you'd want this back? Never mind how odd that seems (to me, anyway) I think this could be done via tasker, or macrodroid. I'm guessing that you can grab the package name, and open it as a URL, which directs back to Google play. I think. I'll have a look, but someone more experienced will probs know ;)

Comment: @DanBrown yeah, I want to give bad ratings to bad apps so that I don't waste my time on them again the next time I install a 100 apps for the same purpose in order to find out which one is best - I'm weird in that way :)

Comment: @beeshyams could you add your comment as an answer? That was enough for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Google Play Store feature and is not dependent on the Android Version

Features of Play store which frequently change or sunset and there is no way to revert to earlier behaviour. For instance, Play Store asks for a review as mentioned here, a feature earlier not present
[Why has Google started asking questions when reviewing apps in Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/167672/131553)